# Either-Or constraints in LPsolveAPI

Tags: optimization, binary, constraints, either, lpsolve

I'm currently writing a MIP in LPsolveAPI in R. The program itself is straightforward, but I can't find a way to write an either-or constraint without being able to directly call a new binary variable or the binary values on the lhs. Does LPsolveAPI not support this or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

The use of new binary variables is the standard way to model either-or-constraints in lp_solve. ([LpSolveAPI](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolveAPI/lpSolveAPI.pdf) is based on the [lp_solve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) solver.). So you are not missing anything obvious.

That said, one thing that might help you, depending on your constraints is the use of SOS (Special Ordered Sets). Check out the [reference to SOS in lp_Solve.](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/SOS.htm)